# Best approach to a line plot (or other type) whose lines consist of an average of 2 Y values

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib

I am wondering the best approach to plot what I want.

I have 4 dataframes of data (2 types of data with 2 replicates for each type). To tis point, I've just been choosing he best replicate of each type and plotting that.

However, I think to be more accurate, I should include both replicates in each line. What is the best way to do this? Box plots? Error bars? Here is an example of the graph I have been creating.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are these true replicates or pseudo-replicates?

Comment: By replicate I mean the data comes from identical samples. Each replicate has slightly different data.

Comment: "comes from identical samples" is still not clear, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mkt I mean I am doing an experiment and I have 2 of each sample type. They are theoretically identical to each other, but due to imperfections give slightly different data. I want to display the variance in the data. I think error bars is the way to go